# How many times to proofread?

Tags: proofreading

How many times to proofread?

Any approximations?

Comment: try leaving a couple of weeks between the proof reads, you will pick up much more if you are approaching it fresh

Comment: Proofread what, and under which circumstances?

Answer (score 5):

Until you are happy with the result and are not finding major issues any more. For some that means one editing and proofreading pass after writing the text; for others, it may mean five.

Comment: You should also ask a co-author or two to do proofreading. We usually overlook our own mistakes.